# Windows Azure Virtual Machines Scheduled Maintenance-March 2014

Tags: azure

We are East US region customer and having single instance Azure VM. We have hosted our production website in Azure VM. We already received mail reg " Windows Azure Virtual Machines Scheduled Maintenance" on Nov 22, 2013. So that we have moved our site to another server and domain look up changed to new server to prevent our productivity loss. But nothing was happened to our Azure VM. We again switched our site to Azure VM.

Current (march 2014 )maintenance will affect our site?

Is possible to check this whether it will affect us or not?

Do we get notification once reboot completed?

Maintenance will affect 6-8 hours or at reboot time alone?

Answer (score 1):

The update may or may not affect your site. Usually what happens during the update is that your VM reboots. If you check your Windows Event Logs, you can see events that indicate that Windows was shut down and the system was restarted.

Usually the maintenance is quick and all you would see is that your VM is down for a few minutes and then reboots and is responding.

In case you want to prevent downtime during updates, you can provision another IaaS VM with your website and put in the same Availability set. By doing this, Azure will ensure that both your VMs do not go down simultaneously. A simple description of how this would look like is given here http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/understanding_configuring_availability_sets_powershell/